# Converting a word from a string array to a char array

Tags: arrays, string, visual-c++, char, type-conversion

Hi I'm working on a hangman project for my class and I've run into a problem. What I'm trying to do is get a list of words from a file then put one random word into a char array but I'm not exactly sure how I'm supposed to convert text form a string array to a char array my code looks like this currently

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   ifstream infile;
   string words[25];
   string wordss;
   char cword[];
   int index=0;
   infile.open("c:\\words.txt)
   while (infile>>words){
         words[index]=words;
         index=index+1;



   }





}
```

Now the originally I was got to simply just make the cword array to a random word for the one of the words array via randomly selected number like cword=words[0] but that didn't work. so I'm wondering how you convert a word selected from a string array to be used for a char array?

Comment: `char cword[]` is wrong for an array declaration. You have to specify the size during declaration.
make `char cword[];` to `const char *cword`
You can then say `cword=words[0].c_str()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char* cword should be used instead of char cword[], that will allow you to store only a single word after allocating memory for it. Lets say your word length is 10 then you will write as
cword = new char[10]; don't forget to delete the memory allocated later by delete [] cword;

String can also do what you are trying to do without converting into char[].
For example you have:-

```
string cword = "Hello"
cout<<cword[2]; // will display l
cout<<cword[0]; // will display H
```

Normally type casting is done by using following 2 statements.

```
static_cast<type>(variableName);   // For normal variables
reinterpret_cast<type*>(variableName);  // For pointers
```

A sample code can be:-

```
ifstream infile;
char words[25][20];

int index=0;
infile.open("c:\\words.txt");
while (infile>>words[index]){
   cout<<words[index]<<endl;    // display complete word
   cout<<endl<<words[index][2];  // accessing a particular letter in the word
   index=index+1;
```

In order to write a good code I will suggest you to stick to only one data type. For this very project.